# Why is my asynchronous GET request working synchronously in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application where I'm implementing asynchronous requests using CompletableFutures. However, I'm facing an issue where my GET request seems to be working synchronously instead of asynchronously. I've included a Thread.sleep() method call for 10 seconds to test if it is waiting for the complete duration or not. If it is waiting for the complete duration, then it is synchronous, otherwise, it is asynchronous.

code is given below:

//service

```
 @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Subscribers> getUserById(int id) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null));
    }
```

//controller

```
   @GetMapping("/getMode/{id}")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> getUserById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return userService.getUserById(id)
                .thenApply(user -> {
                    if(user != null) {
                        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
                    } else {
                        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
                    }

                })
                .exceptionally(ex -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build());

    }
```

It would be helpful to provide some code examples or specific details about your implementation in order to give a clearer understanding of the problem.

Comment: I am lacking sleep myself but *"I've included a Thread.sleep() method call for 10 seconds to test if it is waiting for the complete duration or not. If it is waiting for the complete duration, then it is synchronous, otherwise, it is asynchronous."*  does not seem to be correct.   You are forcing a sleep.

Comment: thank you for your response but i don't understand it can you elaborate ?

Comment: You are calling sleep, **then** you execute your command

Comment: When you use `Thread.sleep` in such manner you first blocking the executing thread and then after 10 seconds return a `CompletableFuture`

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear, so answering based on the given code.

1. Your `sleep(10000)` is called before starting `supplyAsync()` -> so it ***WILL ALWAYS*** wait for 10 secs then executes next instruction, which is `make-an-async-call`. In other words, `sleep()` and `supplyAsync()` are written in synchronous manner.
2. `.thenApply()` will execute after async call completes. Since `async()` call itself starts after 10 secs, then will also happen after 10 secs.

Comment: thank you again for your response but what i want 


1. My Controller should be available for the client side always even after my sevice is taking time then it doesn't wait for it 


2. If the that interval of period 10sec sleep getting that response back